# How can I get the date with the closest previous month from a given row date in a partition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table A

```
Item     Date    

a        01-01-2000   
a        10-05-2000    
a        12-02-2000    
b        01-01-2000    
b        01-31-2000    
b        02-01-2000    
c        01-01-2000
```

i want this output, the closest previous date of the given row for the same item

```
Item     Date          closest_day

a        01-01-2000    null
a        10-05-2000    01-01-2000
a        12-02-2000    10-05-2000
b        01-01-2000    null
b        01-31-2000    null
b        02-01-2000    01-31-2000
c        01-01-2000    null
```

Comment: Is the latest edit to the question correct? The title states "previous" month and `01-01-2000` is not in a previous month to `01-31-2000` and the OP had put that value as `null`.

Comment: sorry about that, I fixed it. Yes the closest date must be in a different month

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
with t as(
select 'a' c,to_date('01.01.2000','mm.dd.yyyy') d from dual
union all   
select 'a' ,to_date('10.05.2000','mm.dd.yyyy')  from dual    
union all   
select 'a' ,to_date('12.02.2000','mm.dd.yyyy')  from dual    
union all   
select 'b' ,to_date('01.01.2000','mm.dd.yyyy')  from dual    
union all   
select 'b' ,to_date('01.31.2000','mm.dd.yyyy')  from dual   
union all   
select 'b' ,to_date('02.01.2000','mm.dd.yyyy')  from dual    
union all   
select 'c' ,to_date('01.01.2000','mm.dd.yyyy')  from dual
)
select t.c,t.d,LAG (t.d) over ( partition by t.c order by t.d ) from t
```

closest date must be in a different month?
ok

```
 with t as(
select 'a' c,to_date('01.01.2000','mm.dd.yyyy') d from dual
union all   
select 'a' ,to_date('10.05.2000','mm.dd.yyyy')  from dual    
union all   
select 'a' ,to_date('12.02.2000','mm.dd.yyyy')  from dual    
union all   
select 'b' ,to_date('01.01.2000','mm.dd.yyyy')  from dual    
union all   
select 'b' ,to_date('01.31.2000','mm.dd.yyyy')  from dual   
union all   
select 'b' ,to_date('02.01.2000','mm.dd.yyyy')  from dual    
union all   
select 'c' ,to_date('01.01.2000','mm.dd.yyyy')  from dual
)
select c,d,case when trunc(d,'Month')<>trunc(closest_d,'Month') then closest_d else null end closest_d  from(
select t.c,t.d,LAG (t.d) over ( partition by t.c order by t.d ) closest_d from t 
)
```

Comment: You're probably right, but that won't match the OP's desired output data at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-left join containing inequality among dates within the join condition :

```
with t2 as
(
select t1.Item,t1."Date" as t1_Date, t2."Date" as t2_Date
  from t t1
  left join t t2 on t1."Date">t2."Date" and t1.Item = t2.Item
)
select Item, t1_Date as "Date", max(t2_Date) as "Closest Day"
  from t2
 group by Item, t1_Date 
 order by Item, t1_Date
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aba29d0101a56a66001d5d5ea7bb647b)</kbd>

Comment: I am not sure that your edit to the question is correct. The OP's title says a "previous" month and `01-01-2000` is not in a previous month to `01-31-2000`.

Comment: Interesting. I really didn't read the title but the excerpt within the text that tells *the closest previous date of the given row for the same item* @MT0

Comment: apologies for the confusion due to my mistake, yes, I am looking for the closest previous date which is not in the same month

Answer (score 0):

From the question title:

> How can I get the date with the closest previous month from a given row date in a partition?

This is specifically addressing the fact that the previous value should be in a "previous" month and not in the same month as the row's date as per the expected results in [Edits 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59076136/1) through [Edit 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59076136/3).

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( item, "date" ) AS
SELECT 'A', DATE '2000-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', DATE '2000-10-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', DATE '2000-12-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2000-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2000-01-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2000-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', DATE '2000-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       ( SELECT MAX( "date" )
         FROM   test_data p
         WHERE  p.item = t.item
         AND    p."date" < TRUNC( t."date", 'MM' )
       ) AS prev_date
FROM   test_data t
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ITEM | date                | PREV_DATE          
> :--- | :------------------ | :------------------
> A    | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | null               
> A    | 2000-10-05 00:00:00 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
> A    | 2000-12-02 00:00:00 | 2000-10-05 00:00:00
> B    | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | null               
> B    | 2000-01-31 00:00:00 | null               
> B    | 2000-02-01 00:00:00 | 2000-01-31 00:00:00
> C    | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76190154a6fd324d89421b6f3a8c98c0)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions -- if I assume that you want the  most recent date *before* the current month for each row.  This uses the `range` window definition:

```
SELECT t.*,
       MAX("date") OVER (PARTITION BY item
                         ORDER BY TRUNC(t."date", 'MON')
                         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING
                        ) AS prev_date
FROM test_data t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ae41716cecb03db964d9946d26d28ea3) is a db<>fiddle.

If you specifically want the result from the previous calendar month, then:

```
SELECT t.*,
       MAX("date") OVER (PARTITION BY item
                         ORDER BY TRUNC(t."date", 'MON')
                         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING
                        ) AS prev_date
FROM test_data t;
```